# In Django, how can I iterate over the result of a custom template tag that requires arguments?

Tags: django, arguments, templatetags

If I have created a template tag:

```
@register.simple_tag
def last_books(a_cat, cutoff=5):
    objects = Books.objects.filter(category=a_cat)
    return objects[:cutoff]
```

How can I do something like this in my template:

```
{% for book in last_books 'Sports' 3 %}
```

I am currently getting this error:

> 'for' statements should use the format 'for x in y': for x in last_books 'Sports' 3

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Personally, I would simply pass in the book as a context variable via the view.  That way you have no need for a template tag.

Alternately, you could use the inclusion_tag decorator instead, which wraps up the idea of rendering an include template with a custom context into the current document.

But if you want to continue on the current path, the `simple_tag` decorator isn't the way to go.  It's for use when you need to return a `string` which you want rendered directly into the template.  What you're trying to do is set a template context variable.  This is a bit more involved, but not too difficult.  Create a node something like this:

```
class LastBooksNode(template.Node):
    def __init__(self, category, cutoff=5, var_name='books'):
        self.category = category
        self.cutoff = cutoff
        self.var_name = var_name
    def render(self, context):
        context[self.var_name] = Books.objects.filter(category=self.category)[:self.cutoff]
        return ''

@register.tag(name='last_books')
def do_last_books(parser, token):
    error = False
    try:
        tag_name, category, cutoff, _as, var_name = token.split_contents()
        if _as != 'as':
            error = True
    except:
        error = True

    if error:
        raise TemplateSyntaxError, 'last_books must be of the form, "last_books <category> <cutoff> as <var_name>"'
    else:
        return LastBooksNode(a_cat, cutoff, var_name)
```

You would then invoke the template tag with:

```
{% import <your tag library> %}
{% last_books 'category' 5 as my_books %}
{% for book in my_books %}
    ....
{% endfor %}
```

Untested, but I hope this demonstrates the idea.  As mentioned above, though, passing the books directly to the view via the context or using an inclusion_tag may be easier if you don't intend to reuse this in multiple places.

Comment: You should include an example of the tag usage such as {% last_books 'Sports' 3 as my_books %}

Comment: You're right, I updated the code sample with more information

Comment: Awesome, this works great.  Thanks!  Things are starting to make more sense to me now.

Comment: Ok found in the [doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/#writing-the-compilation-function), _"separates the arguments on spaces while keeping quoted strings together"_

Answer (score 3):

Why not [with](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#with)?

Comment: Perhaps I'm using "with" incorrectly?  When I try:
    {% with last_books 'Sports' 3 as book_list %}

I get this error:

u'with' expected format is 'value as name'

Answer (score 0):

```
{% last_books sports 3 as last_books %}  # do it like this

{% for book in last_books 'Sports' 3 %}
       ...
{% endfor %}
```

but it's better to use inclusion_tag